# pandas: найти первое вхождение даты для каждого пользователя

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица с несколькими столбцами, в том числе user_id и date. Одному пользователю может принадлежать несколько значений дат. Необходимо найти первое вхождение даты и присвоить ему какой-либо признак (напротив соответствующей строки добавить в новый столбец значение 'first'). Предполагаю что нужно пройтись циклом по таблице, для каждого user_id и date проверить дату, методом first или min и для первой даты сделать запись в новом столбце. Помогите пожалуйста.

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1110 | 2020-02-16 |
| 1110 | 2020-02-15 |
| 9999 | 2020-02-16 |
| 1110 | 2020-01-10 |
| 9999 | 2020-03-16 |

в выводе ожидается:

| user_id | date | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1110 | 2020-02-16 | NaN |
| 1110 | 2020-02-15 | NaN |
| 9999 | 2020-02-16 | first |
| 1110 | 2020-01-10 | first |
| 9999 | 2020-03-16 | NaN |

Update:
Не учел еще один признак в другом столбце, с Вашего позволения усложню задачу. Необходимо найти первое вхождение даты для конкретного iser_id c признаком True и присвоить ему в новом столбце значение 6. Остальные строки в новом столбце заполнить нулями.

| user_id | date | payer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1110 | 2020-01-24 | True |
| 1110 | 2020-01-17 | True |
| 9999 | 2020-02-16 | False |
| 1110 | 2020-01-10 | False |
| 9999 | 2020-02-23 | True |

Вывод должен быть следующим:

| user_id | date | payer | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1110 | 2020-01-24 | True | 0 |
| 1110 | 2020-01-17 | True | 6 |
| 9999 | 2020-02-16 | False | 0 |
| 1110 | 2020-01-10 | False | 0 |
| 9999 | 2020-02-23 | True | 6 |

Глобальный смысл задачи: клиент на первой неделе пользуется триал-версией продукта, на второй неделе у него начинается платная подписка, за привлечение такого клиента бизнес единоразово платит 6 рублей, эту информацию и нужно занести в таблицу. За последующие периоды никаких выплат за клиента нет. Спасибо.

Comment: Где эта таблица? Где воспроизводимый пример исходных данных и пример желаемого результата?

Comment: Скорректировал вопрос, спасибо.

Comment: В  какой конкретно помощи вы нуждаетесь? Надеюсь не "сделайте задание вместо меня"?

Comment: будут рад любому дельному совету, не обязательно решения целиком (естественно я пытался набрать код в юпитере, прежде чем здесь написал), достаточно алгоритма...

Comment: Извиняюсь за неполную формулировку изначальной задачи. Дополнил свой вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
df.loc[df.sort_values("date").
       groupby("user_id").
       apply(lambda x: x.index[0]), "mark"] = "first"
```

получится df:

```
   user_id       date   mark
0     1110 2020-02-16    NaN
1     1110 2020-02-15    NaN
2     9999 2020-02-16  first
3     1110 2020-01-10  first
4     9999 2020-03-16    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного длинный, но работает.

```
df.loc[df.set_index(['name', 'date']).index.isin(df.groupby('name')['date'].min().reset_index().\
                                               set_index(['name', 'date']).index), 'new_col'] = 'first'


>>>   
   name       date new_col
0  1110 2020-02-16     NaN
1  1110 2020-02-15     NaN
2  9999 2020-02-16   first
3  1110 2020-01-10   first
4  9999 2020-03-16     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

чуть покороче:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('user_id')['date'].idxmin(),'new_col'] = 'first'
```

и желательно сразу приводить date к типу datetime

Comment: по поводу комментария про даты - "+"

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось с помощу `sort_values` и  [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.sort_values(by=['id']).drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first')
```